# Where is apc.php?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Using Ubuntu server 10.4, I apt-getted php-apc

Where is the apc.php file that I'm meant to copy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`find / -name apc.php* 2>/dev/null`

"Find, within `/`, resources matching `apc.php*`, and discard stderr."

E.g. this may return `/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download/APC-3.0.19/apc.php`

Comment: I fail to see the sense to piping the output of find to grep in this instance, since find will only return names that contain the searched-for string.

Comment: Otherwise there's "Permission denied" for files that you cannot read.

Comment: This doesn't work for Ubuntu where apc.php comes gzipped.  though `find / -name 'apc.php*'` would have.

Comment: Where permissions errors are sent to STDERR, use `find / -name apc.php* 2>/dev/null`

Comment: ...or you could always run find with sudo and there'd be no need to bother with the whole dev/null malarkey.

Answer (score 40):

Accourding to the packages.ubuntu.com page about [php-apc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/php-apc/filelist) the file can be found compressed here `/usr/share/doc/php-apc/apc.php.gz`.

If you don't want do look online you can query the list of files installed by the package managment system by using a command like `dpkg -L apc.php`.

Comment: Anyone can share the code for that `apc.php` file instead? [Dotdeb does not seem to have included that file in their package.](http://justpaste.me/view/41)

Comment: @WearetheWorld, you could always download a .deb file that does include that, and simply extract the files from .deb.  See http://serverfault.com/a/88522/984 A .deb is an `ar` archive that usually conatains a couple tar.gz files.

Comment: Yeah that's [what I did](https://gist.github.com/Apathetic012/5464439) haha!

Comment: On Ubuntu i had to use `dpkg -L php-apc`.

Comment: Note that for php5.5 the lib is APCU therefore the path is: `/usr/share/doc/php5-apcu`

Answer (score 6):

I came here looking for this file after installing APC on CentOS with PEAR. After tracking it down with Ben's find suggestion, I thought I'd post its path in case others end up here:

```
/usr/share/pear/apc.php
```

Answer (score 4):

From the README.Debian

> 1. Viewing statistics and tunning your cache
>
> APC come with a script called apc.php. This script provides detailed
>   information about your cache. In Debian this script is in
>   /usr/share/doc/php-apc. Copy or symlink the file to your docrot and
>   access it with you browser. If you install the php5-gd package you
>   will also be present with graphics. In order to understand the
>   information and use it to tune you cache refer to the APC
>   documentation at: http://php.net/apc
>
> -- Pietro Ferrari   Wed, 17 Dec 2008 11:23:39
>   -0500

This file was located in `/usr/share/doc/php-apc`

Answer (score 4):

If nothing else works, you can download it directly from PECL by hand:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APCu -O - | tar xz --wildcards apcu*/apc.php
mv apcu*/apc.php apc.php
rm -r apcu*/
# mv apc.php /wherever/you/want/apc.php
```

Comment: No longer works right, they started to rename APC things to APCu

Comment: @ParoX yep, I patched mine by hand but it's currently crashing again, not very realiable at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you. On Godaddy's CentOS virtual hosts this was the only way it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it here for apcu
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krakjoe/apcu/master/apc.php
You can also look through the repo here
https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu

Answer (score -2):

You may consider this as a replacement for apc.php.

https://jorgenevens.github.io/php-cache-dashboard/